# How many pegs inside a geoboard polygon?

Tags: geometry

Can anyone tell me how to solve this problem in a simply way? Thank you very much!

A polygon on a geoboard has an area of 16.5. If it has eleven pegs toughing the geoband, how many pegs are in its interior?

Comment: Where did you encounter this problem?

Comment: Do you know [Pick's Theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pick%27s_theorem)?

Comment: Coud you provide a sketch of what you call a geoboard and a geoband ?

Comment: @JeanMarie I think they mean [these](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=geoboard&tbs=imgo:1). So essentially a board with pegs at all integer coordinates, around which rubberbands -- I mean, "geobands" -- are stretched.

Comment: The problem has no illustration on what a geoboard and a geoband look like.